# Overwriting blocks in jinja

Tags: html, ajax, flask, jinja2

So I'm learning Jinja and am trying to use the extend feature to be able to overwrite a block with new content but it's not working.

home.html

```
      {% block mainBlock %}
   <div id="newNewsCont">
      <div id="leftCont">
        <h2> Tesla Model 3 </h2>
        <p> Model 3 combines real world range, performance, safety and spaciousness into a premium saloon that only Tesla can build. Our most affordable range yet, Model 3 acheives 215 miles of rage per charge while starting at only 35,000 USD before incentives. Model 3 is designed to attain the highest safety ratings in every category. </p>
      </div>

      <div id="rightCont">
        <h2> Reliant Robin LX 3DR 0.9 </h2>
        <p> 2 keys, cherry bomb exhaust, this car turns heads, just had brand new custom made interior fitted, with sound proofing under carpets, just had a full respray in renault 5 gt turbo pearl white </p>
      </div>
   </div>
  {%endblock%}
```

I'm wanting to overwrite it using list.html

```
{% extends "home.html" %}

{% block mainBlock %}
    {% for item in cars %}
        <li> {{ item }}</li>
    {% endfor %}

{%endblock%}
```

server.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, render_template

DATABASE = 'database.db'


app = Flask(__name__)

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

@app.route("/")
def home():
return render_template('list.html', msg = '')

@app.route("/ListCars")
def cars():
cars = ['tesla','reliant robin','Transit Van']
return render_template('list.html', cars = cars)

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? You can take a look at Jinja2 Inheritance section http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#template-inheritance

Comment: Oh I've read that page so many times but it just doesn't make sense to me. I'm wanting the contents of mainblock in list.html to overwrite the content of mainblock in home.html

Comment: What is the result when you load list.html?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the `home.html` design for `list.html`:

list.html

```
{% block mainBlock %}
{{super()}}
...
{%endblock%}
```

if this is not what you want then write the exact problem because your code is fine should work.